# BOOST_FOREACH variant that enables removing currently processed elemement from the container

Tags: c++, boost, foreach, iterator

I was looking for BOOST_FOREACH that would be resistant to removing the currently processed element from the container, where removing element doesn't invalidate iterators (apart the one pointing to the element removed, thus the one that is the foreach holding).
Containers like linked list are typical example of that and as we use boost intrusive lists a lot, the for cycles based on the example are starting to be too frequent.

```
//NumberList is boost intrusive list of structures, containing number property

void removeEvenNumbers(NumberList& numbers)
{
  NumberList::iterator next = numbers.begin();
  for (NumberList::iterator i = numbers.begin(); i != numbers.end(); i = next)
  {
    ++next;
    if (i->number % 2 == 0)
      i->unlink();
  }
```

}

Edit: please note, that the example is solvable by remove_if but in the real scenarios, it is often not usable, or practical.

I'm looking for foreach variant that would allow me to write much more elegant source code.

```
void removeEvenNumbers(NumberList& numbers)
{
  BOOST_FOREACH_RESISTANT(NumberList::value_type& item, numbers)
    if (item.number % 2 == 0)
      item.unlink();
}
```

What is the simpliest way to create this kind of macro from the existing components used to create the original FOREACH in boost?